# In C++ : how to print the digits after the decimal.

Tags: c++

In C++ : how to print the digits after the decimal. 
For example i have this float number ( 12.54 ), and i want to print it like this ( 0.54 ).
Thank you all.

Comment: Why not subtract the integer part from the object and just print it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `modf` function.

```
double integral_part;
double fractional = modf(some_double, &integral_part);
```

You can also cast it to an integer, but be warned you may overflow the integer. The result is not predictable then.

Comment: Do you mean `static_cast<int>(some_double)`? Because that would cut the digits *after* the decimal, not the opposite.

Comment: `some_double` is the double which contain both integral and decimal part. For more information on `modf` refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way

```
float f = 10.123;
float fract = f - (int)f;
std::cout << fract;
```

But for large input you can obtain integer overflow. In this case use

```
float fract = f - truncf(f);
```

Output

```
0.123
```

Answer (score 1):

> In C++ : how to print the digits after the decimal. For example i have
>   this float number ( 12.54 ), and i want to print it like this ( 0.54
>   ).

If you want to use get the fractional part of a floating type number you have a choice of `std::floor` or `std::trunc`. Non negative numbers will be treated the same by either but negative numbers will not.

`std::floor` returns the lowest, non fractional, value while `std::trunc` returns the non fractional towards 0.

```
double f=1.23;
floor(f);  // yields .23
trunc(1.23);  // also yields .23
```

However

```
double f=-1.23;
floor(f);  // yields -2
trunc(f);  // but yields -1
```

So use `trunc` to get the fractional part for both positive and negative f's:

```
double f=-1.23;
f - floor(f);  // yields .77
f - trunc(f);  // but yields -.23
```